# how to add module of python into java using jython jar

Tags: java, python, netbeans, python-2.7, jython

I used Netbeans platform to build my application uasing java languge.I need to invoke some python functions into java class using jython was the only way.
unfortunatly when I tried to run the program an error showed indicate that the application did not find the following modules

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):

File "script.py", line 13, in <module>
    import re
ImportError: No module named re
  File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
    from string import *
ImportError: No module named string
Java Result: 1
```

this is the code in **script.py** that I want to invoke one of it's method into my java class

```
#!/pkg/ldc/bin/python2.1

import xml.parsers.expat
import re
from string import *
import sys
```

How to add these python modules into my application ?

Comment: What happens when you execute your script stand alone (i.e., just `jython script.py` from the terminal)?

Comment: Is your PYTHONPATH correct? It should include location of python libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code runs just fine on my Ubuntu box with Jython 2.7 and Java 1.6 (tested with Eclipse and from the terminal):

```
package myjythonproject;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class MyJythonProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
            PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
            interp.execfile("/home/vicent/foo.py");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure to compile and execute with jython.jar in your classpath.

**UPDATE**

I've just installed NetBeans 7.2.1 (version for Java SE) on my Ubuntu box, created a new Java project, MyJythonProject, and added the code shown above to the MyJythonProject.java file. Then on the `Properties` dialog of the project I've selected `Libraries` in the left pane. In the right pane I've selected the `Compile` tab, clicked the `Add JARF/folder` button and selected my jython jar (/opt/jython2.7a2/jython.jar). The I've closed the Dialog and in the `Run` menu of the main window I've selected `Clean and Build Project (MyJythonProject)`. After that I've run the project and it works like a charm. No Python/Jython plugin required, just tell to your project where the jython.jar is installed.

**UPDATE 2**

Also notice that Python3 is not supported by Jython so you have to use a Python2.x interpreter.

Comment: still get error :(.I added jython.jar into my Netbeans library any idea?

Comment: Is your IDE well configured? I don't use NetBeans but maybe [this link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevelopingJythonAppsUsingNetbeans) can be of help.

Comment: the thing is I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1 and to add python plugin I must downgrade to 6.5 which cues me a lot of problem inside my code. Also I tried many ways to add python plugin into Netbeans 7.2. but they all end up with failure. I think there is simple way to configure the path to python library. Like now I downloaded python and refer to it by using   Properties props = new Properties();
  props.setProperty("python.path", "C:\\Python33");
   PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), props,new String[] {""});  unfortunately still get the same error is it because my path syntax ?!

Comment: Please, see my update. If it doesn't help you then I'll give up :) Just one more think, AFAIK Python3 is not yet supported by Jython so you should use a Python2.x interpreter.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's worked so well :). relay appreciate your time and this useful answer. many many thanks

Comment: @Vicent I tried to do the same, but after adding the jython jar, I had to add `guave, constantine, jruby, antlr-runtime, asm` for it to get to the error `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class` Any idea on what I might have done wrong? I'm on ubuntu14.04, use java 1.7, I have both python 2.7 and 3.4 and I'm not sure which one he chooses, but default should be 2.7.