# Use PythonInterpreter with Jython in Java Code

Tags: java, python, netbeans-7, jython

When I type jython in terminal I get:

```
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.7.0_51
```

I want to use the NLTK POS in my java code. I followed @Vicent answer in [how to add module of python into java using jython jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020382/how-to-add-module-of-python-into-java-using-jython-jar) to use python interpreter,

```
package myjythonproject;

import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class MyJythonProject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
        interp.execfile("/home/vicent/foo.py");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

with only one change on the code:

```
interp.execfile("/Users/ha/Desktop/Code.py");
```

there is no error but the content of Code.py is not displayed(which is only printing Hello world).

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hello World";
```

I've edit the system path from terminal to the jython lib folder.

How can I make it work?

**UPDATE:**

After I added `print __name__` before the if statement - As suggested by @MikeRixWolfe - and I got this output:

```
run:
main
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

so I edit it to `if __name__ == "main":` and it works!

Comment: Perhaps the output may not be where you expect it to be, you may need to call setErr and setOut.

Comment: How can I use setErr in the code I've added? Thanks for ur reply @NESPowerGlove

Comment: PythonInterpreter API should tell you how http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html

Comment: @Evanescence Glad to hear changing `__main__` to `main` works, in hindsight it makes total sense considering java's inherent method naming scheme is without the underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the `__name__` is **not** `__main__` due to it being called from the java program, rather than directly. Try placing `print __name__` above the `if` statement to verify